# Using Moq, how can I detect if a button click fired off an event in my viewmodel?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, prism, moq

The commands:`Click.Command={Binding OkCommand}` in my view (`PopupView.xaml`)

```
<Button
    Name="OKButton"
    Content="{Binding Path=foo.foo, Source={StaticResource LocalResourceWrapper}}"
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=foo.foo, Source={StaticResource LocalResourceWrapper}}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    commands:Click.Command="{Binding OkCommand}"
    Margin="5,10,5,10"
    Click="OK_Click"
    TabIndex="1" />
```

fires off the following command in my viewmodel: (PopupViewModel.cs)

```
    private ICommand _okCommand;

    public ICommand OkCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_okCommand == null)
            {
                _okCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnOKCommand);
            }
            return _okCommand;
        }
    }

    public void OnOKCommand(object someObject)
    {
        this.ReturnSelectionListsCommand.Execute(this.GetAuditOrderByItemList());
    }

    public DelegateCommand<List<AuditOrderByItem>> ReturnSelectionListsCommand { get; set; }
```

Basically I want to detect that the OKCommand is indeed called when the button is pressed. So, I need to manually call the OKButton's click event and ultimately detect that `ReturnSelectionListsCommand.Execute()` and `GetAuditOrderByItemList()` are each called once to guarantee my popup works correctly. From my research, I see that a ButtonAutomation peer can be used to fire off the click, but in my test, I don't see how I can access the OKButton if I'm using MVVM.

In my unit test, I've attempted to use something along the lines of this:

```
var mock = new Mock<PopupViewModel>();
```

to at least detect when methods are called in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to consider using [project white](http://white.codeplex.com/), which is an abstraction over the MicrosoftUI Automation library.

You could use the API to simulate a click on the button, and then mock your view model to set a flag and assert that it has been set.